# Bind DNS Server Error

Tags: bind, dns-server

I try to set up a Bind DNS server, if I test the actual configuration with

```
named-checkzone domain.de /etc/bind/db.domain.de
```

the following error appears:

```
zone domain.de/IN: NS 'ns1.domain.de' has no address records (A or AAAA)
zone domain.de/IN: not loaded due to errors.
```

Unfortunately I don't know how I can fix this problem, please can anyone help? Many Greetings

Content of ect/bind/db.domain.de:

```
$TTL 1D
@ IN SOA ns1.domain.de. email.domain.de. (
2013121100 ; serial
8H ; refresh
2H ; retry
4W ; expire
3H ) ; minimum

@ IN NS ns1.domain.de.
@ IN NS ns2.domain2.de.

@ IN A 192.168.178.22
localhost IN A 127.0.0.1
mail IN A 192.168.178.22
www IN A 192.168.178.22
ftp IN CNAME www
imap IN CNAME www
loopback IN CNAME localhost
pop IN CNAME www
relay IN CNAME www
smtp IN CNAME www
@ IN MX 10 mail
```

Content of ect/bind/db.0.168.192:

```
$TTL 1D
@ IN SOA ns1.domain.de. postmaster.domain.de. (
2013121100 ; serial
8H ; refresh
2H ; retry
4W ; expire
3H ) ; minimum

@ IN NS ns1.domain.de.

10 IN PTR ns1.domain.de.
```

Answer (score 3):

You have specified that your first nameserver should be `ns1.domain.de` but you don't have an IP address assigned to that subdomain.

You should add an A record like this:

```
ns1 IN A 192.168.178.5
```

Your other name server is on a different domain (domain2.de) so the A record for that nameserver should exist in the config for that domain.

I'm not sure but I think you may be able to add an A record for ns2 if you end the domain with a dot and have this IP address be sent back in the additional section when a client requests your NS records.

```
ns2.domain2.de. IN A 192.168.178.6
```